# Saving binary data (pdf) to local storage and loading it using WebView (with PDF.js for Android)

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism, pdf.js

I'm using Xamarin Forms, Prism Unity, PCLStorage, & [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/controls/display-pdf/).

So I'm having two problems; first, the View updates the property too late (i'm using OnNavigatedTo); and second, i'm lost on how to go about loading a local .pdf file using a custom webview.

---

**LocalWebPage.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class LocalWebPage : ContentPage
{
    public LocalWebPage ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Redraw();
    }

    #region Methods
    private void Redraw ()
    {
        StackLayout main = new StackLayout ()
        {
            Spacing = 0
        };

        LocalWebView webView = new LocalWebView ()
        {
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
        };
        webView.SetBinding(LocalWebView.UriProperty, "Source", BindingMode.TwoWay);
        main.Children.Add(webView);

        Content = main;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

**LocalWebPageViewModel.cs**

```
public class LocalWebPageViewModel : BindableBase, INavigationAware
{
    #region Fields & Properties
    private INavigationService _navigationService;

    private string _source;
    public string Source
    {
        get { return _source; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _source, value); }
    }

    public DelegateCommand GoBackCommand { get; set; }
    #endregion

    public LocalWebPageViewModel (INavigationService navigationService)
    {
        _navigationService = navigationService;

        GoBackCommand = new DelegateCommand(GoBack);
    }

    private void GoBack ()
    {
        _navigationService.GoBackAsync();
    }

    public void OnNavigatedFrom (NavigationParameters parameters)
    {
    }

    public void OnNavigatedTo (NavigationParameters parameters)
    {
        if (parameters.ContainsKey("url"))
        {
            Source = parameters["url"] as string;
        }
    }
}
```

**StorageService.cs**

```
public static async Task SaveToCache (string fileName, byte[] buffer)
{
        IFolder rootFolder = FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage;
        IFolder folder = await rootFolder.CreateFolderAsync("Cache", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
        IFile file = await folder.CreateFileAsync(fileName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("LocalStorage: (" + rootFolder.Path + ")");
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Saved to Cache: (" + file.Path + ")");

        using (Stream stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccess.ReadAndWrite))
        {
            stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }
}
```

**LocalWebView.cs**

```
public class LocalWebView : WebView
{
    #region Static Fields & Properties
    public static readonly BindableProperty UriProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Uri),
                                                                                  typeof(string),
                                                                                  typeof(LocalWebView),
                                                                                  default(string));
    #endregion

    #region Fields & Properties
    public string Uri
    {
        get { return (string) GetValue(UriProperty); }
        set { SetValue(UriProperty, value); }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

**LocalWebViewRenderer.cs**

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof(LocalWebView), typeof(LocalWebViewRenderer))]
namespace MyProject.Droid.CustomRenderers
{
public class LocalWebViewRenderer : WebViewRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged (ElementChangedEventArgs<WebView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            LocalWebView localWebView = Element as LocalWebView;

            Control.Settings.AllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs = true;

            // Hardcoded for now because of problem 1.
            string path = string.Format("file://{0}/{1}/{2}", PCLStorage.FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage.Path, "Cache", "Sample.pdf");

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("LocalWebViewRenderer:Android: " + path);

            Control.LoadUrl(string.Format("file:///android_asset/pdfjs/web/viewer.html?file={0}", path));
        }
    }
}
}
```

**Output**

```
[0:] LocalStorage: (/data/user/0/MyProject.Droid/files)
[0:] Saved to Cache: (/data/user/0/MyProject.Droid/files/Cache/Sample.pdf)
...
[0:] LocalWebViewRenderer:Android: file:///data/user/0/MyProject.Droid/files/Cache/Sample.pdf
08-30 17:49:04.104 W/BindingManager( 3709): Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 3709
[0:] LocalWebPageViewModel.Source property changed: Sample.pdf
[INFO:CONSOLE(9665)] "Warning: Ignoring invalid character "60" in hex string", source: file:///android_asset/pdfjs/build/pdf.worker.js (9665)
08-30 17:49:04.921 I/chromium( 3709): [INFO:CONSOLE(9665)] "Warning: Ignoring invalid character "60" in hex string", source: file:///android_asset/pdfjs/build/pdf.worker.js (9665)
...
[INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Unhandled promise rejection", source: file:///android_asset/pdfjs/web/viewer.html?file=file:///data/user/0/MyProject.Droid/files/Cache/Sample.pdf (0)
```